# Как проверить адрес электронной почты на валидность?

Tags: android, android-edittext

У меня в приложении есть два варианта получения эл. почты почты (пока во всяком случае): это получить его с сервера как ответ на мой запрос (сервер мой и поэтому приходит много чего еще кроме почты, и почту приходится тянуть отдельно) либо заставить пользователя ввести его (адрес) вручную в поле для ввода. Что один что второй вариант требует внедрения валидации адреса, то есть мы например все-таки получили адрес, и у нас есть строка, и вот вопрос как сделать эту валидацию. Вот например я тяну адрес почты из памяти устройства, куда я его сохраняю после запроса:

```
sp = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", 0);
String applicant_email = sp.getString("applicant_email", "");
```

либо вот как я его могу получить из поля для ввода:

```
String c = mail_of_sender.getText().toString();
```

где, `mail_of_sender` это поле для ввода. И теперь собственно вопрос - каким образом внедряется валидация и как ее вообще делать? Надеюсь не я первый кто сталкивается с таким вопросом и я думаю что уже есть решение моей проблемы.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kotlin:

```
/**
 * Check the text in EditText on validity of email
 * @return isValid
 */
internal fun EditText.isEmailValid(): Boolean {
    return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(this.text.toString()).matches()
}
```

Java:

```
 public boolean isEmailValid(String email){
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }
```

Comment: а с чем сравнивается? или есть какая-то база адресов?

Comment: У вас был вопрос о валидности адреса. Валидность адреса определяется паттерном

Comment: так а паттерн разве не нужно определить?

Comment: Там регулярные выражения. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns

Comment: Так я же указал всё для проверки)